# How could I make this code displaying Quadratic Bezier curve instead of Cubic Bezier curve?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bezier

This is a **Cubic Bezier curve** and as it is known, ***the cubic Bezier curve has four control points*** as shown the figure below, which are [P0,P1,P2,P3]. According to the Python code example that I have found is giving the starting and ending points and this confused me and I don't know how did he specify the other points. `I'd like to convert it from Cubic Bezier curve to quadratic Bezier curve`. PS. The Quadratic Bezier curve has three control points [P0,P1,P2]. Any assistance, please? How did I put the points to convert it to Quadratic Bezier curve?

***The reason from converting to Quadratic, I need to try it with Path planning problems.***

## Cubic Bezier curve

[image: Cubic Bezier]

## Python code of Bezier

```
"""
Path planning with Bezier curve.
author: Atsushi Sakai(@Atsushi_twi)
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.special

show_animation = True


def calc_4points_bezier_path(sx, sy, syaw, ex, ey, eyaw, offset):
    """
    Compute control points and path given start and end position.
    :param sx: (float) x-coordinate of the starting point
    :param sy: (float) y-coordinate of the starting point
    :param syaw: (float) yaw angle at start
    :param ex: (float) x-coordinate of the ending point
    :param ey: (float) y-coordinate of the ending point
    :param eyaw: (float) yaw angle at the end
    :param offset: (float)
    :return: (numpy array, numpy array)
    """
    dist = np.sqrt((sx - ex) ** 2 + (sy - ey) ** 2) / offset
    control_points = np.array(
        [[sx, sy],
         [sx + dist * np.cos(syaw), sy + dist * np.sin(syaw)],
         [ex - dist * np.cos(eyaw), ey - dist * np.sin(eyaw)],
         [ex, ey]])

    path = calc_bezier_path(control_points, n_points=100)

    return path, control_points


def calc_bezier_path(control_points, n_points=100):
    """
    Compute bezier path (trajectory) given control points.
    :param control_points: (numpy array)
    :param n_points: (int) number of points in the trajectory
    :return: (numpy array)
    """
    traj = []
    for t in np.linspace(0, 1, n_points):
        traj.append(bezier(t, control_points))

    return np.array(traj)


def bernstein_poly(n, i, t):
    """
    Bernstein polynom.
    :param n: (int) polynom degree
    :param i: (int)
    :param t: (float)
    :return: (float)
    """
    return scipy.special.comb(n, i) * t ** i * (1 - t) ** (n - i)


def bezier(t, control_points):
    """
    Return one point on the bezier curve.
    :param t: (float) number in [0, 1]
    :param control_points: (numpy array)
    :return: (numpy array) Coordinates of the point
    """
    n = len(control_points) - 1
    return np.sum([bernstein_poly(n, i, t) * control_points[i] for i in range(n + 1)], axis=0)


def bezier_derivatives_control_points(control_points, n_derivatives):
    """
    Compute control points of the successive derivatives of a given bezier curve.
    A derivative of a bezier curve is a bezier curve.
    See https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#derivatives
    for detailed explanations
    :param control_points: (numpy array)
    :param n_derivatives: (int)
    e.g., n_derivatives=2 -> compute control points for first and second derivatives
    :return: ([numpy array])
    """
    w = {0: control_points}
    for i in range(n_derivatives):
        n = len(w[i])
        w[i + 1] = np.array([(n - 1) * (w[i][j + 1] - w[i][j])
                             for j in range(n - 1)])
    return w


def curvature(dx, dy, ddx, ddy):
    """
    Compute curvature at one point given first and second derivatives.
    :param dx: (float) First derivative along x axis
    :param dy: (float)
    :param ddx: (float) Second derivative along x axis
    :param ddy: (float)
    :return: (float)
    """
    return (dx * ddy - dy * ddx) / (dx ** 2 + dy ** 2) ** (3 / 2)


def plot_arrow(x, y, yaw, length=1.0, width=0.5, fc="r", ec="k"):  # pragma: no cover
    """Plot arrow."""
    if not isinstance(x, float):
        for (ix, iy, iyaw) in zip(x, y, yaw):
            plot_arrow(ix, iy, iyaw)
    else:
        plt.arrow(x, y, length * np.cos(yaw), length * np.sin(yaw),
                  fc=fc, ec=ec, head_width=width, head_length=width)
        plt.plot(x, y)


def main():
    """Plot an example bezier curve."""
    start_x = 10.0  # [m]
    start_y = 1.0  # [m]
    start_yaw = np.radians(180.0)  # [rad]

    end_x = -0.0  # [m]
    end_y = -3.0  # [m]
    end_yaw = np.radians(-45.0)  # [rad]
    offset = 3.0

    path, control_points = calc_4points_bezier_path(
        start_x, start_y, start_yaw, end_x, end_y, end_yaw, offset)

    # Note: alternatively, instead of specifying start and end position
    # you can directly define n control points and compute the path:
    #control_points = np.array([[5., 1.], [-2.78, 1.], [-11.5, -4.5], [-6., -8.]])
    #path = calc_bezier_path(control_points, n_points=100)

    # Display the tangent, normal and radius of cruvature at a given point
    t = 0.86  # Number in [0, 1]
    x_target, y_target = bezier(t, control_points)
    derivatives_cp = bezier_derivatives_control_points(control_points, 2)
    point = bezier(t, control_points)
    dt = bezier(t, derivatives_cp[1])
    ddt = bezier(t, derivatives_cp[2])
    # Radius of curvature
    radius = 1 / curvature(dt[0], dt[1], ddt[0], ddt[1])
    # Normalize derivative
    dt /= np.linalg.norm(dt, 2)
    tangent = np.array([point, point + dt])
    normal = np.array([point, point + [- dt[1], dt[0]]])
    curvature_center = point + np.array([- dt[1], dt[0]]) * radius
    circle = plt.Circle(tuple(curvature_center), radius,
                        color=(0, 0.8, 0.8), fill=False, linewidth=1)

    assert path.T[0][0] == start_x, "path is invalid"
    assert path.T[1][0] == start_y, "path is invalid"
    assert path.T[0][-1] == end_x, "path is invalid"
    assert path.T[1][-1] == end_y, "path is invalid"

    if show_animation:  # pragma: no cover
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.plot(path.T[0], path.T[1], label="Cubic Bezier Path")
        ax.plot(control_points.T[0], control_points.T[1],
                '--o', label="Control Points")
        ax.plot(x_target, y_target)
        ax.plot(tangent[:, 0], tangent[:, 1], label="Tangent")
        ax.plot(normal[:, 0], normal[:, 1], label="Normal")
        ax.add_artist(circle)
        plot_arrow(start_x, start_y, start_yaw)
        plot_arrow(end_x, end_y, end_yaw)
        plt.xlabel('X')
        plt.ylabel('Y')
        ax.legend()
        ax.axis("equal")
        ax.grid(True)
        for i, p in enumerate(control_points):
            ax.annotate(f'P{i:d}', xy=p, xytext=(0,5), textcoords='offset points', ha='center')
        plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Mathematical answer: you can't. Programming answer: you can't, at least not losslessly. So, given that cubic curves are pretty much just as cheap as quadratic curves, but far better: why the heck would you bother? Keep the original: quadratic curves are almost always terrible. Source: I wrote https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Dear, I'm not looking for Mathematical answers. The problem above is coding, I just want to know, how the control points are used in this code. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: @gboffi Dear Sir, as we all know, when we need to draw a Bezier curve, we need to specify the control points until to draw it, but above I saw he just specify the first and last points. This is confused me, I didn't understand it. For this reason, I wanted to understand it and try to make it displaying quadratic.

Comment: @gboffi The post has been modified and the ref. has been added with the code.

Comment: I know it's about programming, but unless you can explain _why_ you need quadratic curves, there is literally no reason to want this other than bad reasons. So: can you please update your post to explain why you need quadratics?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans OK dear sir. I have put a line in my post about the reason. The reason from converting to Quadratic, I need to try it with Path planning problems.

Comment: That is not a reason. General path planning doesn't care about the curve type in the slightest, it just cares about being able to compute the arc length, which any curve library can do. So again: _why do you think you **need** to convert it_?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It's not about converting, my idea is based on this type of curves.

Comment: You literally say "I'd like to convert it from Cubic Bezier curve to quadratic Bezier curve" in your post. So if that's _not_ what you want, please update your post. If it _is_ what you want, clarify why, because unless you already have some library in mind that only works with quadratic curves, you have no reason to prefer them over the vastly better cubic curve. It certainly won't make any appreciable difference for path planning.